# PHP ftp_rename won't work but other FTP commands work?

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to get some PHP ftp commands to work through my website.   All are working, so far, except for PHP_RENAME.      I can create folders, add files, delete files, delete folders... but PHP_RENAME fails.

This is the code that creates the folder:

```
$dir = "/web/proofs/";
$old_dirfolderfile=$dir."oldfolder";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($FTP_SERVER);
ftp_login($conn_id, $FTP_UID, $FTP_PWD);
$result=ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $old_dirfolderfile);
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

This code works fine and the folder is created.

I can delete the folder with:

```
$dir = "/web/proofs/";
$old_dirfolderfile=$dir."oldfolder";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($FTP_SERVER);
ftp_login($conn_id, $FTP_UID, $FTP_PWD);
$result=ftp_delall($conn_id, $old_dirfolderfile);
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Again, no problem.

But this code:

```
$dir = "/web/proofs/";
$old_dirfolderfile=$dir."oldfolder";
$new_dirfolderfile=$dir."newfolder";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($FTP_SERVER);
ftp_login($conn_id, $FTP_UID, $FTP_PWD))
$result=ftp_rename($conn_id, $old_dirfolderfile,$new_diroldfolder);
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Fails... doesn't rename the directory, results = false.

I've tried using ftp_chdir to go to $dir (which changes if checking the return) and then using just the folder names, fails also.   Tried using getcwd() to get the full path and add to the folder name, fails too.

Not sure where to go with this now.

Any suggestions?

ADDITIONAL INFO:
A bit more info...  we can use a third party FTP program or direct FTP connection using Network Neighborhood and manipulate, delete, add the folders.

Comment: did you try the operation directly on the server, without using php ?

Comment: The FTP server probably has rename disabled.

Comment: Did you try to rename the file in GUI FTP client?

Comment: Yes, I can manipulate the folder (and files) directly (including rename) using a 3rd party FTP application or even going through "Network Neighborhood" and renaming it there.   Works fine, manually.